# will this $sort and $limit query use the index or be a blocking in memory sort?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, mongodb-indexes

index:

```
{
  last_logged_in: -1
}
```

query:

```
user.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      age: { $gt: 18 },
      city: { $in: ["chicago", "paris"] }
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      last_logged_in: -1
    }
  },
  {
    $limit: 10000
  }
])
```

It is matching based on fields that are not part of the index, but the $sort is by the indexed field.

Will this query require an in memory sort?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Explain output will show you that the index can be used:

```
{
  stage: 'LIMIT',
  limitAmount: 10000,
  inputStage: {
    stage: 'FETCH',
    filter: {
      '$and': [
        { age: { '$gt': 18 } },
        { city: { '$in': [ 'chicago', 'paris' ] } }
      ]
    },
    inputStage: {
      stage: 'IXSCAN',
      keyPattern: { last_logged_in: -1 },
      indexName: 'last_logged_in_-1',
      isMultiKey: false,
      multiKeyPaths: { last_logged_in: [] },
      isUnique: false,
      isSparse: false,
      isPartial: false,
      indexVersion: 2,
      direction: 'forward',
      indexBounds: { last_logged_in: [ '[MaxKey, MinKey]' ] }
    }
  }
}
```

The lack of a dedicated `SORT` stage is the indication that the index is providing the sort. That said, you'll notice that the scan is not bounded (see the `indexBounds`). So the effectiveness of this index for the query entirely depends on the selectivity of the predicates in the `$match`. If it is highly unselective then the index will be useful. The more selective it becomes, the less effective the index will be.

You could instead consider following [the ESR guidance](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/equality-sort-range-rule/). In your situation this would mean creating the following index:

```
{ city: 1, last_logged_in: -1, age: 1 }
```

I would expect this index to perform better for this query than the single field one that you've referenced.

Comment: Just to confirm, if the index is providing the sort, then regardless of how large the `$limit` is, it will never run out of memory, correct?

Comment: Broadly, I _think_ that sounds correct if you are referring to a single operation running up against the 100MB limit enforced by default prior to 6.0. If the limit and documents are large enough, then it is possible that the requested documents will not be returned in a single batch. So a single query may require multiple batches. But individual batches are capped at 16MB and streaming operations like this do not need to "remember" the information returned in earlier batches. This contrasts with blocking operations that need to process everything at once prior to the first batch is sent.